# jQuery fetch Exact Parent of Child (used UL and LI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm stuck with a scenario where I have an n-level menu and I have to generate an automated header which is intended to work like this.

```
*Module1             *Module2
 -Sub Module 1.1        -Sub Module 2.1
 -Sub Module 1.2        -Sub Module 2.2
 -Sub Module 1.2            *Sub Module 2.2.1
                            *Sub Module 2.2.2
```

If the user selects Sub Module 2.2.2 then the header content should be **Module2 >> Sub Module 2.1 >> Sub Module 2.2.1**. In the same way, if the user selects Sub Module 1.1 then the header should be **Module1 >> Sub Module1.1**.

This menu is basically implemented using normal nested ULs and LIs. Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your html, as the UL and LI nesting will be relevant to an answer.

Comment: Where is the 'header content' supposed to be displayed? What's your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mouseover/click event binding for each of the

.
Use mouseover event if the header display to be very dynamic before selecting the menu.
Use Click event ,to display the header after the user selects the menu
Then take the value the list and display then in the Header.

```
$('.menu-items').mouseover(function(){
    var thisName=$(this).text();
    var name=$(this).parent().parent().find('.menu-name').text();
   $('.header').text(name +" "+thisName);
});
```

Output in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/saiprasad2k6/LQfqT/6/

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the clicked element.
2. Use jQuery.parentsUntil() to iterate over the parents.
   http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/

3 . Collect the attributes of the parents to generate the header string.

```
var pList = clickedElements.parentsUntil('.mainModule'); // identifier of topmost parent

var myStr = pList.map(function () {   return this.html();}).get().join(" >>> ");
```